# Is it possible to have labels on y axis in gnuplot in a vertical line chart?

Tags: gnuplot, linechart

I have tried browsing tutorials and examples about Gnuplot, but none seem to cover problem I have at hand.

I made a mockup of a chart I would like to draw:

[image: Desired plot]

Data would be presented in this manner:

```
Item A  10  80
Item B  24  75
Item C  25  52
Item D  24  45
Item E  30  43
....
```

Number of rows would be higher but only two series'.

I am complete beginner when it comes to Gnuplot, but as Excel can't draw vertical line charts I thought that maybe Gnuplot could be made to but haven't been able to figure out how or if it even is possible at all.

Any pointers on direction I should take are appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer assumes that the columns of the data file are tab delimited.

There are a couple of steps to achieve this:

1. You need to swap x and y coordinates, e.g. use `using 2:0` instead of `using 0:2`.
2. The y-axis needs to be reversed: `set yrange [] reverse`.
3. Use the first column as labels for the y-tics: `using 2:0:yticlabels(1)`.
4. Place key above the plot: `set key above`.

All taken together:

```
set key above
set yrange [] reverse
set datafile separator '\t'
plot 'data.txt' using 2:0:yticlabels(1) with lines title 'Series A', \
     'data.txt' using 3:0               with lines title 'Series B'
```

The result:

[image: Result of the above Gnuplot script]

Comment: if they're not tab delineated, I think you could use something like: `using 3:0:yticlabels(strcol(1).' '.strcol(2))`

Answer (score 0):

As I did some formatting to my graph and decided to share my end result and in the case that someone else runs into similar issue. I might've done this in too difficult way, but it got the job done.

```
set key above center
set yrange [] reverse
set datafile separator '\t'
set style line 1 lt 'dashed' lw 4 lc 'black'
set style line 2 lt 1 lw 3 lc 'black'
set style increment userstyle
set xrange [0:100]
set xtics add 25
plot 'data' using 2:0:ytic(1) with lines title 'Now', \
      'data' using 3:0 with lines title '10 years ago'
```

[image: Sample chart]

Thanks again Thor!